# I am able to var_dump() an array passed by session but I can't do anything else with it

Tags: php, session

This is an array passed by session.

Here is my code:

```
var_dump($result);

array(1) {
    ["result"]=>
        array(3) {
            ["status"]=>
                 bool(false)
            ["message"]=>
                 string(4) "test"
            ["type"]=>
                 string(5) "error"
}

array_key_exists('type', $result)) //returns false
```

Also, I have noticed that assigning something to key "message" produces another "message" key which is accessible...

Comment: array_key_exists('type', $result['result'))  ?

Comment: array_key doesn't recursively search nested arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `type` key exists within the `result` array within the array `$result`

```
array_key_exists('type', $result['result'])) // returns true
```

Comment: This did it, thank you! I cannot believe I actually went to Stack Overflow and asked this question despite looking at my code for last 30 minutes... That's one huge brain fart.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write

`array_key_exists('type', $result['result']);`

I guess it's the same problem with assigning 'message'. You should write

`$result['result']['message'] = 'new message';`